# How can I evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ax}- e^{-bx}}{x\csc(\sqrt{x})} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am struggling  to evaluate this integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ax}- e^{-bx}}{x\csc(\sqrt{x})} dx$$

I tried splitting the fraction and integrating both parts separately by using the Laplace transform but I couldn't make much progress with that. Any suggestions?

Comment: $x\rightarrow u^2$ comes to mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $I(k)$ be
$$
I(k) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-a u^2} - e^{-b u^2}}{u}\sin(k u)du.
$$
You can verify your integral is $I(1)$. Now, differentiate with respect to $k$ to get a standard integral you can look up in a table:
$$
I'(k) = \int_0^\infty \left(e^{-a u^2} - e^{-b u^2}\right)\cos(ku)du = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}}e^{-k^2/(4a)} - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{b}}e^{-k^2/(4b)} 
$$
Now integrate this with respect to $k$ to get
$$
I(1) = \int_0^1\left[\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}}e^{-k^2/(4a)} - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{b}}e^{-k^2/(4b)}\right]dk = \frac{\pi}{2}\left[\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)-\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{b}}\right)\right]$$

Comment: wow, that was a pretty nice observation.

Comment: @DougL Converting annoying integrals into low-order differential equations is a pretty common integration technique. It's also how you get a lot of those integrals that turn out to be Bessel functions or similar.